# Windows Phone Adjust ColumnDefinitions

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, grid

I have this grid divided in three columns but I want to support two columns with Width="0.5*" each and one column with Width="1*". The columns should be filled with data received from a webservice. How can I achieve that requirement based on how many data I receive?

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OtherValue1Label}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OtherValue1Value}" />
  </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OtherValue2Label}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OtherValue2Value}" />
  </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OtherValue3Label}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OtherValue3Value}" />
  </StackPanel>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "based on how many data I receive"? The width of the columns could be different depending on the data from webservice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set 2nd and 3rd `ColumnDefinitions`'s Width property to 0 when only need the 1st column. For example :

```
//set column width to 0
var columns = MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions;
rows[1].Width = new GridLength(0);
rows[2].Width = new GridLength(0);

//set it back to 0.3*
var columns = MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions;
rows[1].Width = new GridLength(0.3, GridUnitType.Star);
rows[2].Width = new GridLength(0.3, GridUnitType.Star);
```

Same approach can be applied when you need the 1st and 2nd columns. Simply set the 3rd column's width to 0.